# What should be done with tag darwiniv?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Today I noticed that there are some questions using the tag [darwiniv](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darwiniv)

The questions are all asked by the same user, and revolve around that planet.

How do you feel about the tag, and what should be done with it?

Personally I am not in favor of a tag specific to a fictional planet of a third party franchisee, and I would rather use the more generic [alternate-earth](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-earth), [earth-like](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-like), [exobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exobiology) or [exolife](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exolife), and merge it with one of them.

Comment: For extra clarity, it seems like the tag refers to [a planet called Darwin IV](https://speculativeevolution.fandom.com/wiki/Darwin_IV)

Comment: Isn't talking about 3rd party content ill-advised, excepted for maybe fan-fiction? If it's only for that kind of world, it's über specific.

Comment: im not sure how that tag could have came into existence, it seems almost useless

Comment: i think darwiniv tag is only used by a single user and those questions somewhat fall into exobiology category so I vote for merging with this tag instead as part of cleaning up ;D

Comment: @user6760, you know that the smiley ;D is used to confer a joking attitude to a sentence? So, is that a serious statement or a joke?

Comment: actually ";D" is meant to show happiness and in case you are mistaken I never joke ;p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Agreed on the removal

Not much to say there, 3rd party material (so only fan-based worlds), which is not that famous on top, so it can't be put into a well-implanted culture. Not much can live by this tag, sooo...

### Into which tag to merge?

I'm doing my naïve kid, but if it's a planet, why not simply merge it into the tag [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets)? Just by looking at the planet's description, it is a bit far from an earth-like planet (0,6 gravity force, 5% vs 70% water covered, humans cannot breath due to too high oxygen...). Hence my proposed proposal.

Comment: I don't think any tag merging is needed. The [[tag:darwiniv]] is just used as the environment, it doesn't really matter it's a planet. In some instances it means different things. Ultimately removing the tag from the questions seems enough - it doesn't sufficiently overlap with any single tag. Other tags can be added for clarification.

Comment: Seems like this has already been synonym-ized, I would've been a lot happier with a blacklist of said tag.

Answer (score 9):

> I am not in favor of a tag specific to a fictional planet of a third party franchisee, and I would rather use the more generic alternate-earth, earth-like, exobiology or exolife, and merge it with one of them.

I believe this is the correct way to go, as we have an official policy for this. [From the help page on tag creation (emphasis mine):](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

> ### When should I create new tags?
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. **You should always favor existing tags**; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that **your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site**.

The questions with the [darwiniv](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darwiniv) tag are already covered by the tags you proposed, so I think they can be merged.